# Examples of PDE with periodic L1 source term

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, periodic-functions

I'm trying to a numerical simulation based on [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X21007538?casa_token=SO9SHdHl2DAAAAAA:2FUwQHzLDTf8YbVqvMkke4ZEJyZvaNaFMDxpkw2CtXbVG5Ebg8DmTXkt3gf_QCg4P2nolkg9wjTB) where they're studying the problem:

$$
\begin{cases}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\Delta_{p} u=f & \text { in } \left.Q_{T}:=\right] 0, T[\times \Omega \\ u(0, \cdot)=u(T, \cdot) & \text { in } \Omega \\ u=0 & \text { on } \left.\Sigma_{T}:=\right] 0, T[\times \partial \Omega\end{cases}
$$

Anyone have any examples for a suitable function $ f $ such that $ f $ is a measurable function periodic in time with period T and belonging to $ L^1 (Q_T) $ ? And can you point me to some articles where the numerical analysis of such problems is studied ? Thanks !

Comment: I think something like $f(t, \boldsymbol x) = \big( \alpha \sin(t) + \beta \cos(t) \big) \cdot \exp(-\Vert \boldsymbol x \Vert ) $ should do the trick, i.e., some periodic function in $t$ and then something that damps for large $\boldsymbol x$.

Comment: @DanDoe thanks !